# R: How to write non-english excel-formulas with XLConnect´s setCellFormula-function?

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

When I write german excel-formulas to a workbook using XLConnect and setCellFormula, the corresponding cells show an error for unresolved names in the formula (displayed as '#NAME?'). When I open the workbook, enter the cells and leave them with the ENTER key, the formulas work.

Is there something wrong with my code? All of this takes place on windows7, with Excel 2010.

```
library(XLConnect)
out_wb <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx", create = TRUE)

createSheet(out_wb, name = "test_data")
writeWorksheet(out_wb, "test_data", header = FALSE, data = 1:50)

createSheet(out_wb, name = "test_calc")

# german formula - cells gives '#NAME?'-error. Result not displayed until you enter the cell and leave it with ENTER
setCellFormula(out_wb, sheet = "test_calc", row = 1, col = 1, formula = "SUMME(test_data!A2:A10)")

# english formula - works as expected 
setCellFormula(out_wb, sheet = "test_calc", row = 2, col = 1, formula = "SUM(test_data!A2:A10)")

# recalculation does not solve the issue
setForceFormulaRecalculation(out_wb, sheet = "test_calc", TRUE)

saveWorkbook(out_wb)
```

Translating formulas manually is not an option, since the formulas are numerous and sourced from a text-file. Any help appreciated.

Comment: In VBA, non-EN-US formulas are brought in with range.FormulaLocal or range.FormulaR1C1Local. Does XLConnect have this capability?

Comment: Have you tried bringing it the non-EN-US formulas as the cell's .Value property? Excel's overhead should convert to formulas if the cell format is not Text or Custom.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks - the vba features you suggest do not apply to XLConnect. Formulas need to be written with that specific functions and are not recognised otherwise.